# Strip date from String with junk data - Java

Tags: java, string, date

I need to know if there is anyway to strip the date alone from text like below using java. I am trying to find something more generic, but couldn't get any help, As the input varies.

Some example inputs:

```
This time is  Apr.19,2021 Cheers
```

or

```
19-04-2021 Cheers
```

or

```
This time is  19-APR-2021
```

I have seen some code which works for trailing junk characters but couldn't find anything if the date is in between the string and if it varies to different formats.

Comment: What is the full range of formats for the date?

Comment: According to the examples given, I would split each `String` by whitespace(s), then check which of the results contains digits and then try to parse them checking all possible patterns.

Comment: By "strip" to you mean "remove", ie so `"19-04-2021 Cheers"` becomes `" Cheers"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `String#replaceAll` here for a regex one-liner approach:

```java
String[] inputs = new String[] {
    "This time is  Apr.19,2021 Cheers",
    "19-04-2021 Cheers",
    "This time is  19-APR-2021",
    "Hello 2021-19-Apr World"
};
for (String input : inputs) {
    String date = input.replaceAll(".*(?<!\\S)(\\S*\\b\\d{4}\\b\\S*).*", "$1");
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

This prints:

```
Apr.19,2021
19-04-2021
19-APR-2021
2021-19-Apr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assume a "date" is any series of letter/number/dot/comma/dash chars that ends with a 4-digit "word", match that and replace with a blank to delete it

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\b[A-Za-z0-9.,-]+\\b\\d{4}\\b", "");
```